# Create SqlXml object instead of string object

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method:

```
public static string UnZipStr(byte[] input)
{
    if (input == null){
        return null;
    }
    using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(input))
    using (DeflateStream gzip = new DeflateStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(gzip, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

But I always get xml text unzipping, it is fact. 
I need to change this method in order to return SqlXml object. 
Unfortunate I'm java developer and cannot solve this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need a SqlXml object or an XmlDocument/XDocument object? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90803/convert-c-2-0-system-data-sqltypes-sqlxml-object-into-a-system-xml-xmlnode) about converting a SqlXml object into an XmlDocument may be related to your needs.

You may be able to do the following:

```
public static string SqlXmlFromZippedBytes(byte[] input)
{
    if (input == null){
        return null;
    }
    using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(input))
    using (DeflateStream gzip = new DeflateStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(gzip, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        return new SqlXml(reader); // From System.Data.SqlTypes
    }
}
```

Here is the documentation on the [SqlXml constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlxml.sqlxml.aspx).